# How can we create a new layout by defining new elements in tkinter ttk widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, tkinter-layout, ttkwidgets

I want to create/modify new elements and define a new layout in tkinter ttk syle but I not sure how to configure that style in a widget.

```rb
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    
    def _initialize_style():
        style = ttk.Style()
        image = tk.PhotoImage(data=image_data, format="gif -index 0")
        style.element_create("Button.button2", 
                                   "image", image, 
                                   sticky="e")
        return style
    
    style = _initialize_style()
    root = tk.Tk()
    button = ttk.Button(root, text='style', style='TButton')
    button.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

can anyone help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Check out following resources:

1. [Official Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html)
2. [Private but very helpful docs](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html)
3. [Tk docs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/)
4. [python tutorial 1](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/ttk-elements/)
5. [python tutorial 2](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/ttk-style/)
6. [python tutorial 3](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/)

I suggest you to edit the exiting layout or create a new them and add a layout to it, as it seems the much infomation of ttk and its examples are not available.